# Tab key doesn't work in IWebbrowser2

Tags: c++, facebook, tabs, atl, iwebbrowser2

I am using an ActiveX control to implement an embedded browser in an ATL app (IWebbrowser2). The problem is, that I can't jump between text fields using the tab key. Pressing the tab key just does nothing. Pressing the Enter key submits the form as expected. 
The problem exists e.g. on the facebook login site.
How can I make the tab key work properly? Must I activate something in the ATL control to make this work?

Thank you!

Fabian

Comment: There are some other keys that don't work: del, insert. But Pos1, PgUp, PgDn work.

Answer (score 2):

This article describes a way how to use IWebBrowser2 in C:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/cwebpage.aspx

In some comments below it, people have exactly the same problem. Seems IWebBrowser2 just has bug and does not translate keyboard messages (not just TAB, but also CTRL+C etc.) to the expected actions. In some comment there has been a workaround:
http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3558959/Re-hot-key-not-work.aspx

However I have no knowledge about ActiveX so I have no idea if this is usable in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Couldn't test it yet as I wasn't able to integrate the code in our ATL project. Could anyone give some hints how to do this with an ATL class using macros such as COMMAND_ID_HANDLER etc.? Thanks!